npm jsonwebtoken verifying token even with wrong secret
I have the following code (Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-g3vtqj?file=index.js):
const { verify, sign } = require('jsonwebtoken');
const token = sign({ id: 123 }, 'signing_key');
const res = verify(token, 'wrong_key');
console.log(res);

It's giving the decoded token even though the token is wrong.
Also on jwt.io its verifying if no token is provided.
I tried checking on a local environment and there the token is generating fine, but that token is invalid on the stackblitz environment

Ok, see what you mean. On Stackblitz the token gets verified.  But if I output the token and try to verify it on jwt.io, I can't verify it with any of the two sevrets, neither 'signing_key', nor 'wrong_key'. If I do it on my pc, everything works as expected and I get a token that can be verified on jwt.io.

@jps correct. Actually I feel there is no signing key getting attached to the token. I got an issue while verifying the token in my local environment where it gave invalid signature to the token thats correctly getting verified on jwt.io. So I tried it on stackblitz and it gave this weird error

Yes, the token created on Stackblitz can be verified with an empty secret on jwt.io. It's like the values 'signing_key' and 'wrong_key' are ignored, but if I try with an empty string '', I get an exception Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value. Very strange. I can't explain that behavior.

This seems to be something to do with Stackblitz - when I try to reproduce locally with Node.js, the verify call fails as expected
